# Solving equations with logical expressions in Maxima

Tags: maxima, clp

I'm trying to find the solutions of a function that contains a logical expression, but with no success so far.

First, I defined several functions:

```
isPlant(x) := is ((x = "tree") or (x = "grass"));
isAnimal(x) := is ((x = "cat") or (x = "dog"));
isLiving(x) := is (isAnimal(x) or isPlant(x));
```

Next, I tried to find all solutions of an equation with these functions, but none of the solutions were obtained:

```
solve([Living(x) = true], [x]); //this returns an empty list instead of [x = "cat", x = "dog", x = "tree", x = "grass"]
```

Is is possible to obtain solutions of these functions in Maxima?

Comment: Maxima doesn't have anything built in to handle equations like that. I think maybe [Prolog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog) is more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

The solve function assumes that the domain is a set of numbers.  If we first specify the domain

```
(%i) domain : {"tree","grass","cat","dog"};
(%o)                     {cat, dog, grass, tree}
```

then we can use the `subset` function to find the solutions of the equations.

```
(%i) subset(domain,lambda([x], is(isPlant(x)=true)));
(%o)                          {grass, tree}
```

The functions you've defined are predicates, and so return the values `true` and `false`, which means that the equations `predicate(x)=true` are equivalent to `predicate(x)`.  For example, `IsLiving(x)=true` if and only if `IsLiving(x)`.  So rather than finding the elements of the domain which are solutions of the equation `predicate(x)=true`, we can find the elements of the domain which satisfy the predicate, which is more concise.

```
(%i) subset(domain,isLiving);
(%o)                     {cat, dog, grass, tree}
(%i) subset(domain,isPlant);
(%o)                          {grass, tree}
```